# How to loop arrays so one fills up whilst the other empties into the serial monitor?

Tags: arrays, loops, arduino, isr

I am an amateur when it comes to Arduino coding, so I am reaching out on here for help as I cannot find the answer anywhere else.

I have data coming in from a microphone on A0, the Arduino then takes this data every 125ms using an internal interrupt and stores it in an array in the ADCH.  From here I want the data to, once the array is at max capacity of 500 to empty into the Serial monitor.  Whilst this happens I need a second array to take the data from A0, store it in ADCH and dump it into the Serial Monitor once full.  I need these two to arrays to loop continuously without losing any vital data.

Can anyone help please, I have done a lot of searching and I simply haven't found the answer, a point in the right direction is needed, please.

[arduino code I've written so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/927JE.png)

Comment: Code should be posted as text, not as image. Regarding your problem, the conditional assigns to the variable a instead of comparing. You can implement a circular buffer with two indexes, one for writing into the buffer and the other for reading data from the buffer and send it via serial.

Comment: First time I've ever used this site and didn't know that until now, so thank you for your advice there.  I have edited the code to take into account what you have said and it now works.  Thank you again, my understanding of indexes was lacking somewhat.

Comment: It's OK, don't worry, we've all been new users at some point. I suggest you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about the [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your next questions on the site.